# No auto-mute option in alsa

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones

While using the computer(Ubuntu 20.04 and Win10), the sound from the headphones does not work, I only hear everything from the speakers. In alsamixer, I have no option to enable the automute or manage the audio from the headphones. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: yes Ubuntu 20.04